# corrupted size vs. prev_size Error: Command "npm run build" exited with SIGABRT`

Tags: next.js, vercel, blogs, contentlayer

```
Creating an optimized production build ...
Generated 11 documents in .contentlayer
corrupted size vs. prev_size
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with SIGABRT`
```

When deploying my project to vercel it's showing this error and can't deploy my blog website which is using contentlayer.

How can I solve this problem?